# I am getting 'Query execution was interrupted' error while updating wp_post?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am getting `#1317 - Query execution was interrupted` error msg while updating wp_post. The size of this table in my database is around 429MB. I am running the following query.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET comment_status = 'open', ping_status = 'open' WHERE comment_status = 'closed';
```

And i am not able to update the Database Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: Guessing your host has a query timeout set and you're exceeding it. Some hosts have extremely short timeouts, CloudFoundry's is 3 seconds.

Comment: That is my issue I don't know how to change query timeout.

Comment: Usually it's not something they'll let you do. What you can do to get around it is break up your update statement into smaller chunks that won't timeout using some field on the table. You can use the date, or the primary key. wp_posts has an `auto_increment primary key` so you could break it up based on that. Run `select max(id) from wp_posts` to see how many posts there are total. Figure out a logical way to break them up, every 1000, or 2000 etc. Then run your update statement again but filter the id ie `where id < 1000` then `where (id >= 1000 and id < 2000)` etc

Comment: Thank you very much MagicMan you solved my problem.

Comment: I'll make it an answer and you can mark it correct so if other folks have the same issue they can easily see what the answer is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it's not something they'll let you do. What you can do to get around it is break up your update statement into smaller chunks that won't timeout using some field on the table. You can use the date, or the primary key. `wp_posts` has `an auto_increment primary key` so you could break it up based on that.

Run `select max(id) from wp_posts` to see how many posts there are total. Figure out a logical way to break them up, every 1000, or 2000 etc.

Then run your update statement again but filter the id ie: `where id < 1000` then `where (id >= 1000 and id < 2000)`

Would look something like this:

`UPDATE wp_posts SET comment_status = 'open', ping_status = 'open' WHERE comment_status = 'closed' and id < 1000;`